# Why has my .tabs li:hover property stopped working?

Tags: html, css, hover

My page no longer applies the :hover effect to my .tabs li element, but I can't for the life of me figure out why. I commented out my jQuery script and it still won't work.

Here's a JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/qpmg4wzq/

```
  <div id="tabs-container">
    <ul class="tabs">
      <li class="tab current" data-tab="tab-1">tab 1</li>
      <li class="tab" data-tab="tab-2">tab 2</li>
      <li class="tab" data-tab="tab-3">tab 3</li>
      <li class="tab" data-tab="tab-4">tab 4</li>
    </ul>
  </div>


#tabs-container {
  float: left;
  width: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.tabs {
  padding: 0px;
  list-style: none;
  clear: left;
  float: left;
  left: 50%;
}

.tabs li {
  display: block;
  float: left;
  right: 50%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 10px 20px 5px 20px;
  cursor: pointer;
  font-size: 1.1em;
  line-height: 2em;
  -webkit-transition: color .2s linear;
  -moz-transition: color .2s linear;
  -ms-transition: color .2s linear;
  -o-transition: color .2s linear;
  transition: color .2s linear;
  -webkit-transition: background .2s linear;
  -moz-transition: background .2s linear;
  -ms-transition: background .2s linear;
  -o-transition: background .2s linear;
  transition: background .2s linear;
}

.tabs li:hover {
  background: #88abc2!important;
}

.tabs li.current {
  background: #d0e0eb;
  color: #49708a;
}

.tab-content {
  display: none;
  padding: 15px;
  line-height: 1.4;
}

.tab-content.current {
  display: inherit;
}
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `.tab-content` is overlapping the `.tabs-container` so any :hover action you make is actually registering as a hover on the `.tab-content` element.

A couple of options to solve this

1. Move the `tab-content` down using `margin-top`

   ```
   .tab-content.current {
       display: inherit;
       margin-top: 60px;
   }
   ```
2. Remove `float: left` from `#tabs-container`